# split data by a sequence of number using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data

```
head(stockAtt)
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 34201.549405  X        T    1
2: 2018-12-03 34201.549405  P        T   28
3: 2018-12-03 34301.549405  P        T   28
4: 2018-12-03 35401.549405  T        T   36
5: 2018-12-03 35501.549405  T        T   36
6: 2018-12-03 36601.549405  T        T   36
7: 2018-12-03 36101.549405  Z        T    3
8: 2018-12-03 36801.549405  Z        T   23
9: 2018-12-03 37001.549405  Z        T   16
10: 2018-12-03 39001.549405  X        T    5
```

And I have a sequence of time in seconds which can be viewed as bins.

```
seq(from = 34200, to = 40000, by = 1000 )
[1] 34200 35200 36200 37200 38200 39200
```

And I want to split the data.table by "TIME" based interval of the sequence like below.

```
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 34201.549405  X        T    1
2: 2018-12-03 34201.549405  P        T   28
3: 2018-12-03 34301.549405  P        T   28
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 35401.549405  T        T   36
2: 2018-12-03 35501.549405  T        T   36
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 36601.549405  T        T   36
2: 2018-12-03 36101.549405  Z        T    3
3: 2018-12-03 36801.549405  Z        T   23
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 37001.549405  Z        T   16
         DATE         TIME EX SYM_ROOT SIZE
1: 2018-12-03 39001.549405  X        T    5
```

Comment: r u looking for `split(DT, DT[, cut(TIME, seq(from=34200, to=40000, by=1000))])`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 exactly! Could you explain why you use `DT[, cut(TIME, seq(from=34200, to=40000, by=1000))]` here? It seems that `DT[, cut(TIME, seq(from=34200, to=40000, by=1000))]` and `cut(DT$TIME, seq(from=34200, to=40000, by=1000))` have the same return.

Comment: if u see `data.table::split`, the 2nd argument is looking for a factor to split the data.table. `DT[, cut(TIME, seq(from=34200, to=40000, by=1000))]` provides this factor. see `?cut` for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1) using `data.table::split`

```
split(DT, DT[, cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))])
```

2) using `cut` within `by`

```
DT[, .(.(as.data.table(c(.(TIME=TIME), .SD)))), by=cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))]$V1
```

or

```
DT[, tm := TIME][, .(.(.SD)), by=cut(tm, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))]$V1
```

3) Another method as suggested by jangorecki in the comment:

```
data.table:::split.data.table(DT[, cut_col := cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))], by="cut_col")
```

The workhorse is really `cut`. From help on `cut`:

> cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall.

---

some timings:

```
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e7
DT <- data.table(TIME=rnorm(nr, 37100))
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
DT4 <- copy(DT)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    split_f=data.table:::split.data.table(DT, f=DT[, cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))]),
    split_by=data.table:::split.data.table(DT2[, cut_col := cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))], by="cut_col"),
    by1=DT3[, tm := TIME][, .(.(.SD)), by=cut(tm, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))]$V1,
    by2=DT4[, .(.(as.data.table(c(.(TIME=TIME), .SD)))), by=cut(TIME, seq(34200, 40000, 1000))]$V1,
    times=3L
)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  split_f 691.6382 716.6919 748.6798 741.7457 777.2006 812.6554     3   a
 split_by 840.0505 910.3817 938.2106 980.7129 987.2906 993.8683     3   a
      by1 738.8859 749.1444 797.0015 759.4029 826.0593 892.7157     3   a
      by2 623.7743 667.5200 720.1821 711.2658 768.3860 825.5063     3   a
```

Comment: `split.data.table` is actually using `by` itself, you can use verbose arg to examine

Comment: I suggest to first create column with `cut` and then use `split(DT, by="cut_col")`. Second argument in split method is not `by` AFAIR

Comment: thanks, jangorecki and thank you so much for your work on `data.table`!